# Comparing variability of two groups of multivariate data points

Tags: hypothesis-testing, variance, multivariate-analysis

I have a number of samples (data points) from two experimental groups, A and B (500 altogether). Each sample corresponds to a large number of variables (genes in my case); together, they form a matrix of $500 \times 40000$. I would like to answer the question, are samples in group A on the general more variable than samples in group B? The biology of the problem suggests that this might be the case (read, this is the hypothesis that I want to test).

I thought I might do the following: for each group, calculate the multivariate center of the group (by taking sample-wise means for each variable, for example), then calculate the euclidean (or some other) distance to the centre for each sample in the group and then the variance of the distance. Then, do the same for the other group. I am well aware that this is a very naive approach.

What would be the advisable approach?

Comment: There are many bioinformatic tools available.Check http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Genetics.html and http://proteomics.case.edu/r_packages.html

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track with calculating the distances to the group centers.

In general, you are looking for a multivariate version of the test for the homogenity of variance (with $H_0$: "Variances are equal across the two groups", which would allow you to reject that the variances are equal). Since you haven't mentioned any assumptions you are allowed to make (like the normality assumption) I will assume the two distributions aren't normal.

The vegan package in R has a function [betadispers](http://cc.oulu.fi/~jarioksa/softhelp/vegan/html/betadisper.html), which as far as I understand should be exactly what you are looking for, a multivariate version of the Levene's test. The procedure behind the test was developed by M.J. Anderson and is described [here](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~mja/prog/PERMDISP_UserNotes.pdf).

Last detail, you will have to calculate the distance of your gene observations that are stored as matrices. So you will have to concatenate both of them into two vectors of length (2e7 = 500x40000). Which makes me wonder, is there any particular reason why they were stored as matrices in the first place? Is there perhaps some spatial structure that would get lost during concatenation, which would be potentially important for the variance comparison?

If the structure isn't a problem concatenate ahead!

Comment: The approach you propose assumes that the data follows a elliptical distribution on each group's subspace (which is fine: as a matter of fact, I don't see any alternative in this case.) I just want to stress out that the description of this method as one devoid of 'ANY' assumption is not warranted.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I added a correction in the answer. I must admit I haven't dealt much with this property of distributions, hence I don't really know what are non-elliptical distributions. I am guessing that a trivial example of a non-elliptical distribution would be any mixture of discreet and continuous variables. It would be great if you could comment briefly on which part of the above test breaks if the distribution is not elliptical, or post a link providing some further information.(I guess in case of categorical variables, computing the distance would be an obvious candidate).

Comment: Sure: elliptical distributions are distributions whose density contours are elliptical. Counterexamples include multivariate skewed  distributions such as the skew normal. Notions such as (multivariate) centre of symmetry, covariance matrices and PCA decompositions do not in general describe non elliptical densities very well.